# jQuery not even being called

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I don't know what's going on here..I'm trying to add a slidetoggle on my menu .. seems very simple ..  I've tried to simplify this to try and find the problem (meaning I've taken all the links out and extra jquery, to only have that bottom example - the paragraph at the end) but I don't know what the error is.. (other that it doesn't do anything)

Includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/raceday/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button").click(function() {
    $("p").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="ttl-area">
   <h2 class="ttl-account"><span>Account</span></h2>
</div>
<div class="account-area">
   <div class="login-holder">

      <p><strong>Welcome, <%= ViewModel.Profile.Name.First %></strong></p>

      <ul class="account-links">
         <span id="loginTitle">User Options</span><br /><br />
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<EventController>( x => x.List(), "All Events" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<MyEventsController>( x => x.List(), "My Events" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>( x => x.Edit(), "My Profile" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<ClubController>( x => x.List(), "All Clubs" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<MyClubsController>( x => x.List(), "My Clubs" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>( x => x.ChangePassword(), "Change My Password" )%>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<DependantController>( x => x.List(), "My Dependants" ) %>
         </li>

      </ul>
   </div>
  <% if ( ViewModel.Profile.HasOrganizerInfo ) { %>
  <div class="login-holder">
     <ul class="account-links">
        <span id="loginTitle">Organizer Details</span><br /><br />
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>( x => x.Organizer(), "Organizer Details" )%>
        </li>
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<EventController>( x => x.Edit( default(int?) ), "Post An Event" )%>
        </li>
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<EventAdminController>( x => x.List(), "Events Created By Me" ) %>
        </li>
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<ClubController>( x => x.Edit( default( int? ) ), "Create A Club" )%>
        </li>
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<ClubAdminController>( x => x.List( ), "Clubs Created By Me" )%>
        </li>
         <!-- if ( ViewModel.Profile.IsAdministrator ) { -->
         <li>
            <%= Html.ActionLink<EventReportController>( x => x.List(), "Event Report" ) %>
         </li>
         <!-- } -->
     </ul>
  </div>
  <% } %>
  <% if ( ViewModel.Profile.HasTimerInfo ) { %>
  <div class="login-holder">
     <ul class="account-links">
        <span id="loginTitle">Timer Details</span><br /><br />
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>( x => x.Timer(), "Timer Details" )%>
        </li>
        <li>
           <%= Html.ActionLink<EventTimerController>( x => x.List(), "Events Timed By Me" ) %>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <% } %>
      <ul class="account-links">
      <% if ( ( !ViewModel.Profile.HasOrganizerInfo ) || ( !ViewModel.Profile.HasTimerInfo) ) { %>   
         <span id="loginTitle">Additional Options</span><br /><br />
      <% } %>         
         <% if ( !ViewModel.Profile.HasTimerInfo ) { %>
            <li>
               <%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>( x => x.Timer(), "I Time Events" )%>
            </li>
         <% } %>

         <% if ( !ViewModel.Profile.HasOrganizerInfo ) { %>
            <li>
               <%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>( x => x.Organizer(), "I Organize Events" )%>

            </li>
         <% } %>

            <li><%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>( x => x.Logout(), "Log Out" ) %></li>
      </ul>

</div>
        <button>Hide 'em</button>

  <p>Hiya</p>
  <p>Such interesting text, eh?</p>
```

Comment: Is the binding being called after the actual button displayed? If not, wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function(){...}` or use `live` instead of `bind`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code needs to be in a `document.ready` handler so the `$("button")` selector finds elements to bind `click` handlers to.

```
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").slideToggle("slow");
  });   
});
```

If the DOM isn't ready yet, the `<button>` elements may not be added/ready either, which means that `$("button")` will still bind to all elements it finds...but *it won't find them*, resulting in a total lack of behavior, which is what you're seeing.

Comment: very helpful! Dare I go for one more?

a) I want to have the script for each header, but I don't want to have 20 different functions to slideToggle

Comment: @Kevin - In that case you find the element relatively, say each was beside the `<div class="login-holder">`, then instead of `$("<p>")` you might do `$(this).siblings(".login-holder").slideToggle();`, make sense?

Comment: yeah but that didn't really work well with that <div> .. clicking one will close a different one ..

Comment: @Kevin - Doh, your structure's a bit different, you probably want `.next(".logic-holder")` instead of siblings...just depends on where you place the +/- element.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a .next?

Comment: @Kevin -Yup, it selects the next sibling *if* it matches the selector...I can't tell you exactly what to use because I have no idea where your +- element is in relation to what it's toggling, my point was just find it relatively from `$(this)` using the tree traversal methods:  http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: $(".login-holder").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".login-holder").slideToggle();
    });
    })

But it only toggles on the first div

Comment: @Kevin - I would ask a new question with your markup for this...too hard to make out in comments.

Comment: Hi Nick - I've made a new question ... think you can help out?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859072/multiple-slidetoggle-one-function

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap it a load method:

```
$(document).load(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("p").slideToggle("slow");
    });
})
```

Comment: I did have that .. still no dice

Comment: `$(document).load(func...` doesn't work. You can use `$(document).ready(func...` (or its shortcut, see Nick's answer), or `$(window).load(func...` if you want all elements to be fully loaded.

Comment: @patrick - good catch on the `.load()` completely glanced over that.

Answer (score 0):

tried something like this?

```
jQ = jQuery.noconflict();

jQ("button").click(function() {
    jQ("p").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

maybe asp is messing with your $