# Why doesn't jQuery work on my site?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery not even being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857608/jquery-not-even-being-called)

Funny thing is, on jsfiddle it works perfectly if I select the latest jQuery option from the left panel. 
The website is basically a test page to run this menu function.
HTML:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('a.expand').hover(function() {
  $('#Menu').slideToggle();
});



</script>
<a href="" class="expand">
<p>hello!</p>
</a>
<div id="Menu">
wowtest
</div>
```

It's a PHP file if that helps.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txeD9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because there is no `a.expand` element when you execute the script, as the elements are declared after.

Put your code at end of the body or use [a ready callback](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) by changing it to

```
<script>
   $(function(){
    $('a.expand').hover(function() {
      $('#Menu').slideToggle();
    });
   });
</script>
```

Writing `$(function(){ somecode });` asks jQuery to execute `somecode` when the DOM is ready.

Comment: isn't the class attribute related to a.expand? and ok will try that

Comment: The problem is that the DOM (the elements of the page) aren't yet present when you run your script.

Comment: Thanks! used the ready callback it it works!!! And wow thanks for the info this will help so much in the future.